# UserDefaults return 0 elements when call in awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell` and I'm using UserDefaults to save an array of the selected item in `didSelectItem` function to keep selected state after dismissing the parent view controller of them:

```
var arrSelectedIndex = [IndexPath]()
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: arrSelectedIndex)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "arrayOfSelectedItem")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

And whenever I show up the view controller I set my array with UserDefaults again in awakeFromNib:

```
arrSelectedIndex = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayOfSelectedItem") as? [IndexPath] ?? [IndexPath]()
```

But both my array and the UserDefaults return 0 elements (I tried to print out value of arrSelectedIndex and `UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayOfSelectedItem") as? [IndexPath] ?? [IndexPath]()`) and both of them is 0 even if they have data when selected item. Does awakeFromNib reset all things inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is to save the list in userDefault it not necessary to archive it, You can if contains basic data types.
Second, If you archive the list before saving it to UserDefault, Then You have to unarchive the encoded data to get the list.

Here is the method,

```
data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "arrayOfSelectedItem") as? Data
arrSelectedIndex = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [IndexPath] ?? [IndexPath]()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry but I have one more issue. I used this way to save selected items and whenever I dismiss the parent view I remove all things of UserDefaults but the `data` still keep the value even if I rebuild the app. I cannot remove it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayOfSelectedItem") as? [IndexPath]
```

That will fail, because what you saved under that key is not an array. Here is what you said earlier:

```
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: arrSelectedIndex)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "arrayOfSelectedItem")
```

What you saved is `encodedData`. It is not an array. It is a Data. The array is encoded inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. I have tried to unarchive before setting it to my array again and it's worked.